# CSS positioning issues while resizing

Tags: css

Here is what happens:
Initial:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2f19.jpg)

Now when I resize it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAIkj.png)

This is what happens. The buttons move up:

```css
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url('bacimg2.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-top: 13px;
}

.logo {
  height: auto;
  width: 84%;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  float: left;
  width: 14%;
  height: 97%;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(207, 135, 81, 0.8);
}

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-55%);
}

.nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-family: "century Gothic";
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="general.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>The Great CS50 Bakery</title>
  <link href="logotop-removebg-preview.png" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body>

  <section>
    <nav class="nav">

      <img src="logo-PhotoRoom.png-PhotoRoom.png" class="logo">


      <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html" class="current">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="variety.html">Our Variety</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="order.html">Place Order</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="content" id="content">
      <p>THis is a test</p>
    </div>

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Could someone show me how this can be fixed and what else I am doing wrong?
Thanks!!

The Styling seems to be off and changing the position type does not seem to work.

Comment: Are you using a doctype at the beginning? You also aren't using the meta viewport attribute.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Played around with your code a bit and this is the result. Commented out some of your stuff and added what I changed. I recommend you look into [Boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) and [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) :)

```
{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
 background-image: url('bacimg2.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 padding-left: 12px;
 padding-right: 12px;
 padding-top: 13px;

}

.logo {

 height: auto;
 width: 100%; /* was 84% */
 /* position: absolute; */
}


.nav {
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
/* transform: translateY(-50%); */
 float: left;
 width: 14%;
 height: 100vh; /* was 97% */
 border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(207, 135, 81, 0.8);
}

.nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0px;
 /* position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-55%); */

}

.nav ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 22px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 font-family: "century Gothic";


}
```

[image]